# How can I improve performance of average method in SQL?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm having some performance problems where a SQL query calculating the average of a column is progressively getting slower as the number of records grows. Is there an index type that I can add to the column that will allow for faster average calculations?

The DB in question is PostgreSQL and I'm aware that particular index type might not be available, but I'm also interested in the theoretical answer, weather this is even possible without some sort of caching solution.

To be more specific, the data in question is essentially a log with this sort of definition:

```
table log {
  int duration
  date time
  string event
}
```

I'm doing queries like

```
SELECT average(duration) FROM log WHERE event = 'finished'; # gets average time to completion
SELECT average(duration) FROM log WHERE event = 'finished' and date > $yesterday; # average today
```

The second one is always fairly fast since it has a more restrictive WHERE clause, but the total average duration one is the type of query that is causing the problem. I understand that I could cache the values, using OLAP or something, my question is weather there is a way I can do this entirely by DB side optimisations such as indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The performance of calculating an average will always get slower the more records you have, at it always has to use values from every record in the result.

An index can still help, if the index contains less data than the table itself. Creating an index for the field that you want the average for generally isn't helpful as you don't want to do a lookup, you just want to get to all the data as efficiently as possible. Typically you would add the field as an output field in an index that is already used by the query.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I'm just slow to comment. I downvoted because I felt your answer was simply explaining how the typical b-tree indices can help with the filtering. All the lookup columns and the one I'm calculating the average on have indices, and the lookup is fast. It's the average calculation that is slow because of the number of values it's averaging. What I was fishing for is the name of a data structure that creates a b-tree of one column and stores the total of another column for rows that match a given node in the b-tree, or a statement that no such thing can reasonably exist.

Comment: @Sindri Traustason: So what you were hoping for was an index that could group on some fields, and keep a running total for another field for each group? I don't think that something like that is supported in any regular relational database. For the example that you added to the question, you would create an index for the fields `event` and `data`, with `duration` as an output field. That way the query can use the output from the index for the average calculation.

Comment: Accepted answer is in Guffas second comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you are doing?  If you aren't filtering the data then beyond having the clustered index in order, how else is the database to calculate an average of the column?

There are systems which perform online analytical processing (OLAP) which will do things like keeping running sums and averages down the information you wish to examine.  It all depends one what you are doing and your definition of "slow".

If you have a web based program for instance, perhaps you can generate an average once a minute and then cache it, serving the cached value out to users over and over again.

Comment: There are some sneaky things you can do with indexed views, but we need a more concrete example to help you.

Comment: My definition of slow in this case is: Is already noticeably slow and will get slower with time.

Answer (score 2):

Speeding up aggregates is usually done by keeping additional tables.

Assuming sizeable table `detail(id, dimA, dimB, dimC, value)` if you would like to make the performance of AVG (or other aggregate functions) be nearly constant time regardless of number of records you could introduce a new table

`dimAavg(dimA, avgValue)`

- The size of this table will depend only on the number of distinct values of dimA (furthermore this table could make sense in your design as it can hold the domain of the values available for dimA in detail (and other attributes related to the domain values; you might/should already have such table)
- This table is only helpful if you will anlayze by dimA only, once you'll need AVG(value) according to dimA and dimB it becomes useless. So, you need to know by which attributes you will want to do fast analysis on. The number of rows required for keeping aggregates on multiple attributes is `n(dimA) x n(dimB) x n(dimC) x ...` which may or may not grow pretty quickly.
- Maintaining this table increases the costs of updates (incl. inserts and deletes), but there are further optimizations that you can employ...

For example let us assume that system predominantly does inserts and only occasionally updates and deletes.

Lets further assume that you want to analyze by dimA only and that `id`s are increasing. Then having structure such as

```
dimA_agg(dimA, Total, Count, LastID)
```

can help without a big impact on the system.

This is because you could have triggers that would not fire on every insert, but lets say on ever 100 inserts.

This way you can still get *accurate* aggregates from this table *and* the details table with

```
SELECT a.dimA, (SUM(d.value)+MAX(a.Total))/(COUNT(d.id)+MAX(a.Count)) as avgDimA
FROM details d INNER JOIN
     dimA_agg a ON a.dimA = d.dimA AND d.id > a.LastID 
GROUP BY a.dimA
```

The above query with proper indexes would get one row from `dimA_agg` and only less then 100 rows from `detail` - this would perform in near constant time (~log<sub>fanout</sub>n) and would not require update to `dimA_agg` for every insert (reducing update penalties).

The value of 100 was just given as an example, you should find optimal value yourself (or even keep it variable, though triggers only will not be enough in that case).

Maintaining deletes and updates must fire on each operation but you can still inspect if the id of the record to be deleted or updated is in the stats already or not to avoid the unnecessary updates (will save some I/O).

Note: The analysis is done for the domain with discreet attributes; when dealing with time series the situation gets more complicated - you have to decide the granularity of the domain in which you want to keep the summary.

**EDIT**

There are also [materialized views](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views#Definitions), [2](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/69.en.html), [3](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materalized_Views)

Comment: I'm curious: how to make a trigger that only fires once each n times triggered (like your example)?

Comment: @DrColossos, well strictly speaking it must fire every time, but you can make trigger do some real work only on `id % 100 = 0`

Comment: sequences are *not* guaranteed to have no holes, so having holes is possible and missing a round (or rounds) is possible (depending on how often you get to call `nextval('foo_key_seq')` without actually inserting rows), in practice this will not break the system but only change the performance (on average you should be able to find the number of targeted inserts that will work for you)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but indexes won't help much since average must read all the record (in any order), indexes are usefull the find subsets of rows, ubt if you have to iterate on all rows with no special ordering indexes are not helping...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for, but if your table has some way to order the data (e.g. by date), then you can just do incremental computations and store the results.

For example, if your data has a date column, you could compute the average for records 1 - Date1 then store the average for that batch along with Date1 and the #records you averaged.  The next time you compute, you restrict your query to results Date1..Date2, and add the # of records, and update the last date queried.  You have all the information you need to compute the new average.

When doing this, it would obviously be helpful to have an index on the date, or whatever column(s) you are using for the ordering.